# Google Sheet Script - Applying 2d array with different size sub arrays to Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've parsed a json response from an API to a 2d array
and now that I've built the array I want to display it on my sheet however This is my dataarray
It has 413 rows and those rows have varying amounts of data (row 0 is the header row with 67 fields, but not every row has all 67 fields of data in it)

[image]

This is the code I'm using to try and write the data to my sheet (shProductData is a variable I defined earlier in the code to identify my sheet)

```
shProductData.getRange(1,1,dataArray.length,dataArray[0].length).setValues(dataArray);
```

However I get the error:

*Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 40 but the range has 67.*

It writes the header row to my sheet first but then fails on the next one. Is there any way around this? Or am I going to somehow make my sub arrays all be 67 in size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add empty cells at the end of short rows in the data this way:

```js
var data = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5],
    [6,]
]

// get max length of rows in the data
var max_length = Math.max(...data.map(x => x.length));

// add empty cells at end of short rows
data.forEach(row => { while (row.length < max_length) row.push('') } )

console.log(data); // output: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, '' ], [ 6, '', '' ] ]
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked perfectly thank you!!
I can't figure out, what does x=>x.length part of the math function do?
(would like to understand how the code works)

Comment: `data.map(x => x.length)` returns the array of lengths of all rows of the data: `[3,2,1]`. Then it takes max value from the array with `Math.max(3,2,1)` -> `3`